# Magit doesn't prompt for SSH key after OS upgrade?

Tags: magit

**Q:** magit no longer prompts me for my ssh key when pushing/pulling; how do I fix it?

After an OS upgrade (Lubuntu 19.04 to 19.10), I can no longer push
to origin from magit.  Pushing to origin results in a process that
hangs when invoked from magit; I have to kill that process
manually.  The problem seems to be that Emacs no longer prompts me for my public ssh key, and just sits there humming quietly to myself while git waits for it.

Pushing from a terminal using the same command that
magit uses works as expected, since I can enter my ssh key unimpeded.

How do I figure out what could be causing this to happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to an update to OpenSSH 8.1. that changes the confirmation prompt when connecting to a new remote. The [issue](https://github.com/magit/magit/issues/3969) has been fixed a couple weeks ago.

Updating magit should be enough.